# Wrong encoding for downloaded files

Tags: macos, mac, safari, encoding

I try download files from my university site. All I can found it Safari -> View -> Encoding, but it doesn't affect to downloaded files. For example file with cyryllic name: "Задания для групп 80-104Б и 80 109Б на 19.05.2020.docx"
 is downloading like Ð¨Ð»Ñ‹ÐºÐ¾Ð²Ð° Ð›.Ð. Ð—Ð°Ð´Ð°Ð½Ð¸Ñ Ð´Ð»Ñ Ð³Ñ€ÑƒÐ¿Ð¿ 80-104Ð‘ Ð¸ 80 109Ð‘ Ð½Ð°. How can I fix it?
May be it another question, but sometimes safari also can't download file with correct file name (in english), as usual for torrent files. Just cut it.

I tried use another browser as Firefox and there is good work, that's why i think it's problem only safari ill.

Comment: Just use a browser that works.  There's no way to fix such problems with Safari.

Comment: @TomGewecke there is the way to ask Apple fix it?

Comment: Http://www.apple.com/feedback